# Bitcoin Historical Price API/Database

Tags: api, database

I have found many APIs and databases that exist for historical Bitcoin prices but they will only give you data for daily intervals or tick data.

Is there an API / database that exists that will allow a query for data by interval?

Example:
Query the last 500 closes for 5 minute intervals or query OHLC data?

Comment: What do you mean by 'tick data?'

Comment: Tick Data as in every single trade on a particular exchange. For example I can get the last 2000 trades from some exchanges, but I don't necessarily want all trades. Just the OHLC information for each time interval. Similar to the data that would be used to build a candle chart.